# Solving a set of trig inequalities

Tags: trigonometry, inequalities

I have a set of inequalities

```
Cos[a]Cos[b]>=Cos[t-a]Cos[b]&&Cos[a]Cos[b]>=Cos[t/2]&&Cos[a]Cos[b]>=Sin[t/2]&&a<=t<=Pi
```

How to solve this to get a range of values for `a,b,t`?

Comment: Reducing trigonometry to algebra by `Reduce[ca*cb >= ((ct^2 - st^2)*ca + 2*ct*st*sa)*cb && cb*ca >= ct && 
  cb*ca >= st && ca^2 + sa^2 == 1 && cb^2 + sb^2 == 1 && 
  ct^2 + st^2 == 1, {ct, st}, Reals]`, one obtains a huge output.

Answer (score 5):

`RegionPlot3D`shows the region of possible solutions

```
RegionPlot3D[Cos[a] Cos[b] >= Cos[t - a] Cos[b] && Cos[a] Cos[b] >= Cos[t/2] &&Cos[a] Cos[b] >= Sin[t/2] && a <= t <= Pi, {a, -Pi/2, Pi}, {t, 0, Pi}, {b, -1, 1}, AxesLabel -> {a, t, b}]
```

[image]

Comment: Why `{b, -1, 1}` and `{a, -Pi/2, Pi}`?

Comment: -1. `RegionPlot3D[
 Cos[a] Cos[b] >= Cos[t - a] Cos[b] && Cos[a] Cos[b] >= Cos[t/2] && 
  Cos[a] Cos[b] >= Sin[t/2] && a <= t <= Pi, {a, -Pi, Pi}, {t, -Pi, 
  Pi}, {b, -Pi, Pi}, AxesLabel -> {a, t, b}]` shows a bigger region.

Comment: @user64494 Why this children's egg "-1" again and again? My answer shows part of the solution.

Comment: @UlrichNemann: If you admitted in your answer that the plot in your answer draws only a part of  the solution set, I  didn't do my downvote. However, you didn't it.

Comment: @user64494 The same old story over and over again... By the way I didn't mention wether my answer  shows  the complete solution

Comment: UlrichNeumann (@ does not work.) Please be correct. Your claims do not make a good impression.

Answer (score 1):

Reducing trigonometry to algebra by `Reduce[ca*cb >= ((ct^2 - st^2)*ca + 2*ct*st*sa)*cb && cb*ca >= ct &&    cb*ca >= st && ca^2 + sa^2 == 1 && cb^2 + sb^2 == 1 &&    ct^2 + st^2 == 1, {ct, st}, Reals]`, one obtains a huge and useless output.  In order to obtain a concrete result, you have to specify `a` and `b`, e.g.

```
a = 1/20; b = Pi/6; Reduce[Cos[a] Cos[b] >= Cos[t - a]*Cos[b] && Cos[a]*Cos[b] >= Cos[t/2] && 
Cos[a]*Cos[b] >= Sin[t/2] && a <= t <= Pi, t, Reals]
```

> `2 ArcCos[1/2 Sqrt[3] Cos[1/20]] <= t <=  2 ArcSin[1/2 Sqrt[3] Cos[1/20]]`

Try `a=0.05;b=Pi/6;` on your own.

Comment: It should be noticed that `ClearAll[b]; a = 1/20; Reduce[
 Cos[a] Cos[b] >= Cos[t - a]*Cos[b] && Cos[a]*Cos[b] >= Cos[t/2] && 
  Cos[a]*Cos[b] >= Sin[t/2] && a <= t <= Pi && b > -Pi && 
  b <= Pi, t, Reals]` returns the input.